# Swift/iPad OS Network-Free Communication

Tags: swift, ipad, telecommunication

Is it possible to let two Apps on two iPad communicate with each other, wothout them having a connection to the Internet?

My Problem is, that I want to create an app, where Multiple iPads communicate. So i have two or more iPads. Every single one of them has multiple (changeable) Variables and i want to be able to see every iPads Variables on every other iPad. If wifi or Cellular Network is available, i want to have communication over the Internet (more Range), but when these Options are not available, I want to have direct Communication.

Is this possible and how far would the communication be possible?

I found the Multipeer Connectivity Framework. How far is the Range using this?

Thank you for your Answers! 100 Meters at most with the Multipeer Connectivity Framework.

Comment: Depends on a technology: if the pears are on Wi-Fi (which is one of the underlying methods to connect peers), then it can be quite wide (e.g. peers on university network can talk on opposite sides of university). But if you are saying you want to consider cases where devices are not connected to any network, then what remains is bluetooth. And that can handle... maybe 100 meters at most?

Comment: Multipeer Connectivity Framework will work for your needs. Look here for an example; https://www.kodeco.com/12689804-getting-started-with-multipeer-connectivity

Comment: Thanks for your answers, then I need to try if it is enough for my needs